# Status bar not hidden in Vivo v11 Pro

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to Hide status bar within my application using Vivo V11 pro device. Exactly like whatsapp does in its story board.

I have tried conventional ways to do this

getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Expacted result is like how Whatsapp hides status bar behind camera :

[As you can see, Status bar is fully hidden and Horizontal progress bar goes behind the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNjST.jpg)

However, In my case, Status bar is hidden but blank space remain in place of it :

[Here, status bar is not shown but blank space is coming.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPc2o.jpg)

I have searched all the questions related to status bar hiding but have not get satisfactory answer.